# In Rails 3.x or 4 how do you capture the statement that caused a validation error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've used the execute around design pattern that is articulated in the book Eloquent Ruby to log validation errors in my rails application.

I'm capturing the errors using:

```
@o.errors.full_messages   #{:first_name=>["can't be blank"]}
```

and then persisting them to a logs table, but I'd also like to capture the actual method/code that caused the error. For example:

```
User.create(:last_name => "Doe")
```

How would capture the method that caused the errors so I can log it to my validation log table.

Comment: Are you sure you need that? Most of the times it could be just a save() call...

Answer (score 1):

not really sure if this is what you need, for rails 3.2:

```
irb(main):008:0> user = User.create()
```

then getting errors from it:

```
irb(main):009:0> user.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xaa84c60 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, role: "user", approved: false>, @messages={:email=>["can't be blank"], :password=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

they are at the end of the response.

And also you can call errors on create action without saving the user into a variable:

```
irb(main):010:0> User.create().errors
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xa390d78 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, role: "user", approved: false>, @messages={:email=>["can't be blank"], :password=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

at the end you get the same hash with errors:

```
@messages={:email=>["can't be blank"], :password=>["can't be blank"]}
```